# How to send dynamic data as an array from database from controller to view in .net mvc5?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5

```
This is what I got on the web:

In Controller:
 int count = ems.SupportAdds.Where(x=>x.ArticleId == id).Count();

                  var stringArray = new string[count]{"",""}; //Here,I want to fetch data from table.

                  ViewBag.Collection = stringArray;

But, I want to send data dynamically which will come from the database using entity framework.

In View :

           @for (int i = 0; i <= Count; i++)
            {
           @Html.LabelFor(model => @item.supportAdd.Title)
          <input type="text" name="Title[]" id="HeadingTitle" 
            Value="@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Collection[i])"/>
            }
```

I am not getting logic how to send data to the view by the controller.

I am unable to send collection of data to view.

Previously, I have used to send using viewbag, but it was runtime binding error.

I am not getting any clue how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index(User person)
{
string constring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= path";
string cmdText1 = "select * from tablename where EmployeeID='" + person.EmployeeId + "'";

using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(constring))
{
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(cmdText1, connection);
connection.Open();
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
List<User> x=new List<User>();
while (reader != null && reader.Read())
{
//user table holds eid,type,date
User d1 = new User
{
EId = reader.GetValue(0).ToString(),
Type = reader.GetValue(1).ToString(),
Date = reader.GetValue(2).ToString()
x.Add(d1);
};

}
ViewBag.ListData = x;
reader?.Close();  
con.Close();
return View("Home");
}
}

 In View:
@foreach (var p in ViewBag.ListData)
{
<tr>
<th height="30">@p.EId</th>
<th>@p.Type</th>
<th>@p.Date</th>
</tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For passing any collection value to View you can use foreach to get each value

In **Controller:**

```
 var stringArray = new string[]
 {
 "Manual", "Semi", "Auto", "SSS"
 };
 ViewBag.Collection = stringArray;
```

In **View**

```
foreach(var p in ViewBag.Collection)
{
@for (int i = 0; i <= Count; i++)
{
@Html.LabelFor(model => @item.supportAdd.Title)
<input type="text" name="Title[]" id="HeadingTitle" value="@p"/>
}
}
```

-This code is not tested

Comment: Thanks But I want to send data from database dynamically using this method...Is there any way to do that??eg: In place of values like Manual, semi, etc, I want to fetch the collection of data from database table.

Comment: @Siddarth Rajput you can get data from database to controller and then you can pass it to View

Comment: How? Any brief using array

Comment: List<T> listData = new List<T>();
                while (reader != null && reader.Read())
                {
                    T ad = new T
                    {
                        EmployeeId = reader.GetValue(0).ToString(); //get any number values from database
                      listData.Add(ad);
                    }; ViewBag.x= listData;  return View("VIEWPAGE");}     In View you can use for each

Comment: Perhaps you should test it - then you would no that it does not work - it does not even compile!

Comment: You mentioned you are using EF. So once you have it configured and your entities mapped to DB tables, you can have a DbSet of your entities, for example a DbSet of SupportAdds. That's already a collection. You can use that as your source of data to be sent to the view.

Comment: @SiddharthRajput, reader is an object of type OleDbDataReader, which is an Ado.Net standard class.
Ado.Net is a set of classes that help in getting data from the DB. But you mentioned you want to use EF; which is a different tool for a similar purpose.

Comment: Thanks for warm help but Hey, Is there any alternative so that I can use it in asp .net as I am using asp.net MVC 5?